# How to replace specific values in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array like this:

```
var array = [1,3,5]
```

And every number must be replaced by a specific value (i.e. `1` is `"Tree"`, `3` is `"Car"`, and so). So the final array that I want in this example is:

```
var defArray = [Tree, Car, Dog]
```

I tried using `indexOf` and replacing values by Index, but it's not working.

Comment: Show us the code you tried and tell us what precisely is not working.

Comment: [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: Please [demonstrate any research you've done](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/) and [attempts you've made](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/) to solve the issue yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
let array = [1,3,5];
let def = {1: "Tree", 3:"Car", 5:"Dog"};

let r= array.map(x=>def[x]);

console.log(r);
```

Comment: This answer is best because it's easily expandable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're trying to do, but without a doubt the "map" function is what you need.

```
const array = [1,3,5];

const defArray = array.map( e => {
    switch(e) {
        case 1: return "Tree";
        case 3: return "Car";
        case 5:return "Dog";
        default: return transform = "...";
    }
})
```

Answer (score -1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map
The map() method creates a new array with the results of calling a provided function on every element in the calling array.

```
    const inputArray = [1,3,5];
    const outputArray = inputArray.map( i => {
        if(i === 1) return "Tree";
        else if (i === 3) return "Car";
        else if (i === 5) return "Dog";
        return; //you might want to have a default return if nothing matches, up to your specific code's use case.
    }
```

Comment: You don't need else if, because the return at each if statement will short-circuit the loop.

Comment: @JohnSnow The function will exit at whichever matches first, so using else if or just if doesn't add or detract from runtime. It's just a matter of preference and readability.